# colon in colum name causes java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name

Tags: sql, groovy

I've been getting a `"java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name"` error when I try to select each row with an attribute name that contains a colon (for example `"item:one"`.

In my code the following line is called:

```
if (!(matGroup == null || matGroup.equals(''))) {
    sql.eachRow("select distinct da.item_name from defined_attribute da where da.attribute2=$matGroup") {
        selectItems << it.item_name
        }
}
```

If I run the same select command directly to the database (`select distinct da.item_name from defined_attribute da where da.attribute2='item:one'`), I receive no errors. I have also tried the code with item names containing no colon and those seem are retrieved correctly.

I've found here: http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/Sql-is-it-possible-to-escape-the-colon-td5155389.html that adding `"sql.enableNamedParameters = false"` might solve the problem, however, I'm constrained to use groovy 2.1.6, and that is not supported.

I've also tried other things to work around the colon, but neither have been successful. Things I've tried include:

Defining the parameter in a collection

```
def params = [matGroup]
sql.eachRow("select distinct da.item_name from defined_attribute da where da.attribute2=?", params)
```

Escaping the colon before passing it to eachRow()

```
def params = [matGroup.replaceAll(":", "\\:")]
sql.eachRow("select distinct da.item_name from defined_attribute da where da.attribute2=?", params)
```

Defining the command as a string before passing it to eachRow()

```
def command = "select distinct da.item_name from defined_attribute da where da.attribute2='" + matGroup + "\'"
sql.eachRow(command.toString())
```

Is there a way to make this work for groovy 2.1.6?

Comment: Would be curious to know if using the unicode escape for the colon character would work. Probably won't, but it might be worth trying...

Comment: Tried it, but it doesn't work.

Comment: It strikes me that the first query example (before the collection example) doesn't have the parameter in single quotes.

Comment: I had tried that before but adding single quotes around it is actually a security vulnerability, and in any case, it doesn't solve the problem:
WARNING: In Groovy SQL please do not use quotes around dynamic expressions (which start with $) as this means we cannot use a JDBC PreparedStatement and so is a security hole. Groovy has worked around your mistake but the security hole is still there. The expression so far is: select distinct da.item_name from defined_attribute da where da.attribute2='?'

Comment: Can you try enabling logging to see what is actually getting sent? http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/Problems-enabling-SQL-logging-td353390.html sounds like it's a problem elsewhere

Comment: @tim_yates Enabled to FINEST, but not much more than with STDERR:
FINE: select distinct da.item_name from defined_attribute da where da.attribute2=? | [002]
FINE: select distinct da.item_name from defined_attribute da where da.attribute2=? | [ITM:ONE]
WARNING: Failed to execute: select distinct da.item_name from defined_attribute da where da.attribute2=? because: Invalid column name
INFO  [STDOUT] Exception in GetItm.groov Invalid column name
ERROR [STDERR] java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name
ERROR [STDERR]  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.getColumnIndex(OracleStatement.java:3711)

Comment: Can you try logging on the oracle end? This sounds like an oracle issue (but I've not seen it before) :-\

Comment: @tim_yates I added the loggers for 'oracle.sql' and 'oracle.jdbc.driver' but neither provided more information that was already there, just repeats of the same FINE and WARNING messages as before.

Comment: Could this be a case where the matGroup being passed in is actually a Map, i.e [ itm: one ] instead of the STRING "itm:one".  Try using ${matGroup.toString()} in the query... or print out what class matGroup is.